# Python, django, html: I made a booking form and I would like to set this page to login access only without inheriting 'LoginRequiredMixin'

Tags: python, django

In other words, user can not access this booking_form.html without login.

```
<a href="/booking_form/">Booking</a> 

or 

<button onclick="location.href='/booking_form/'">Booking</button>
```

If user hit the button, then they need to login first to access that page. if login successfully, then they would be on the page of booking_form automatically

This one has to be done without inheriting 'LoginRequiredMixin'...

Answer (score 1):

```
try below code probably works in your HTML template.

{% if user.is_authenticated  %}
<a href="/booking_form/">Booking</a> 
{% else %}
 your logic here
```

you can attach the login_required decorator to your login view

```
@login_required
def view_name(request):
```

Comment: sorry I did not make what I meant clear.... user who has not logined yet hit the button (it has to be shown to user) and then login require (need to be authenticated), finally user would be on the booking_form

Comment: ok then simply set @login_required in your view so when URL map with the view at this moment view will redirect to login page

Comment: Excellent! it works. easything. one more question? after login, not to redirect /home/ but to /booking_form/.... do I need to adjust url redirect? I would like to set this up only this case... I mean usually redirect always to /home/ but only this case to /booking_form/ after login

Comment: yes you can set in your login  view

return redirect("your URL path")

Comment: you can  HTTP_REFERER for redirect back to where user came
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/

Comment: Thanks but if I set login view return redirect '/booking_form/' then every users who log in would be redirected to '/booking_form/' ... what I wanted to do is that I wanna set this only who this buttom on this page. is it possible?

Comment: sorry, but I not understood.